# Rails, Paginate with an or statement in the conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, will-paginate

So basically I have two types of status' and I'd like to display both properties with status_id "2" and status_id "5", properties never have two status' so I know I don't want to use an & here, I'd like to be able to have and or statement but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. This is what I have to show just status_id "2" and it works just fine.

```
@properties = Property.order("updated_at DESC").paginate(:per_page => 20, :page => params[:page], :conditions => { :status_id => '2' })
```

in my model I also have scopes that look like the following, not sure if I could do it that way...

```
scope :for_sale, joins(:status).where(:statuses => { :current => 'For Sale'})
scope :market_listings, joins(:status).where(:statuses => { :current => 'Market Listing'})
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `:conditions` in the `paginate` call, it would IMO be clearer and easier to use `where` like this:

```
@properties = Property.where('status_id = 2 or status_id = 5').order("updated_at DESC").paginate(:per_page => 20, :page => params[:page])
```

This is also possible:

```
@properties = Property.order("updated_at DESC").paginate(:per_page => 20, :page => params[:page], :conditions => 'status_id = 2 or status_id = 5')
```

Or even simpler:

```
@properties = Property.order("updated_at DESC").paginate(:per_page => 20, :page => params[:page], :conditions => { :status_id => [2,5] })
```

Comment: The `where` statement worked best to keep things out of the paginate call. Thanks a Bunch!